# Accounting for uncertainty in a fit coefficient

Tags: error-analysis

I am trying to analyze data from a Fabry-Perot interferometer where I measure the intensity profile of light from a helium neon laser in order to calibrate it to measure the hyperfine structure of mercury's green transition line.

So, I have the following image,
[image]
which has a radial intensity profile that looks like 
[image]

My goal is to then fit that intnesity profile to the following function, which is supposed to describe these ring patterns from a FP interferometer
$$
I_T=\frac{I_0}{1+F \sin\bigg(\frac{2\pi d}{\lambda}\frac{f}{f^2+r^2}\bigg)}
$$
where $I_T$ is intensity at a given value of $r$, $F$ is known as the coefficient of finesse which is related to the resolving power of the interferometer, $d$ is the plate separation of the interferometer, $f$ is the focal length of the lens I've used and $\lambda$ is the wavelength of my helium neon laser.

I have measurements of $\lambda$ and $f$. So, I would like to fit for $d$ and $F$. The concern I have run into though, is that I realize now that my measurement of $f$ has a huge amount of experimental error in it and I'd like to account for that in my fit, however I don't really understand how. My knowledge of curve fitting has only informed me of what do to with errors in my measurements of $I_T$ and $r$.

I sense a couple ways to deal with this but would like some advice on the best way to proceed. One thing to do is Monte-Carlo simulations. I could run the fit 1000 times for $f$ and $\lambda$ with a gaussian error in them with width proportional to my estimate of their uncertainty, and then measure the variance of the set of Monte-Carlo fit parameters for $d$. This seems like a bit of a pain in the ass, but also doable.

Another approach would be to propagate my estimated error in $f$ into my estimated error in $I_T$, ie. do the following transformation to my estimated error in $I_T$ 
$$
\delta I_t \rightarrow \sqrt{(\delta I_T)^2+\bigg(\frac{\partial I_T}{\partial f}\delta f\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{\partial I_T}{\partial \lambda}\delta \lambda\bigg)^2} 
$$
and then just weigh my data by this transformed uncertainty in my fit.

I'm wondering if any of you have opinions on which of these is the 'better' method here.

I understand that subjective questions are discouraged here, so let me phrase this as follows: Should the two methods I discussed give the same or similar results? Why or why not? Is there a more correct or less labour intensive way to account for error $f$?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about statistics and is better suited for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I suppose that is a fair stance to take, but if that is the case, what is the point of the physics stack exchange having an error analysis tag? Error analysis is a integral part of doing physics, and many physicists know a lot about error analysis that they can share here. That said, I have also posted this question to Cross Validated, though I'd appreciate if this question stayed open.

Comment: That's also a fair point -- but there isn't anything specific here to physics. For example, if you needed to know what form an error might take in order to propagate through, that would be very physics specific. Is the error in a frequency, say, Gaussian? Exponential? Uniform? Etc.. But as it stands, there's not even units or an identification of what the variables in your model mean -- so it's pretty divorced from physics.

Comment: And it still takes 4 more to agree with me for it to be put on hold. It's entirely likely others won't agree and nothing happens!

Comment: @Mason - I think that error analysis is a legitimate topic here. On the other hand, your question as posed is completely devoid of any apparent connection to physics. All we see is an equation with no physical meaning attached to it or any of its parameters. It might as well be in a pure statistics or mathematics forum as it now stands.

Comment: Those are fair points! I will edit my question to bring out the physics.

Comment: @tpg2114 does my edited question conform better to your standards?

Comment: @Mason Much better -- vote retracted.

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but you might be interested in using something like [Dakota](https://dakota.sandia.gov/) from Sandia to do your analysis. It can do the Monte Carlo -- but there are many other algorithms depending on what ends up being best for your case. It's what we use for uncertainty quantification.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that an analysis program like Mathematica (or Igor, Matlab) can do a least squares fitting of your first equation to your  IT vs. d data with F, d, and f as fitting parameters. The Mathematica function is "FindFit". The one complication I see is that the fitting parameters d and f may closely mimic each other if f is small compared to most of your range of r values. It would be best if you could simply read off the value of the lens focal length f or otherwise determine it exactly rather than having to include it as a fitting parameter. Why is it necessary to measure f?

Comment: @SamuelWeir I am not trying to find $f$ as a fitting parameter, it is a constant I have already measured, but it's error has turned out to be very significant due to the flawed way I found it. So, I want to include the value for $f$ that I measure ($69\pm2$mm), but I would like it's (large) error to be taken into account in the fit.

Comment: @Mason - I guess that you could fix f to various values from, say, 69-2 mm to 69+2 mm and then fit your IT vs. r data with F and d as fitting parameters. By seeing how much the fitted F and d vary as f is stepped across its range of values, you would get a handle on the uncertainties associated with F and d if f is only known to a certain accuracy.